# Visibility problems with the screen on Linux running in a Virtual Box after update to the latest version

Tags: ubuntu

I updated my Ubuntu to the latest version on my Virtual Box, but after the update I can't see the screen completely. I've put a screenshot of the problem I'm facing.

Thank you for the help.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

resolved! you have to terminate your session, so close the virtual machine. Now open again your vm and it will work!